# How to change text alignment in QTabWidget in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtabwidget

This is the same question as in:
[How to change text alignment in QTabWidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607709/how-to-change-text-alignment-in-qtabwidget)

I tried to port that python code into C++ but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is header file:

```
#include <QTabBar>

class HorizontalTabWidget : public QTabBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HorizontalTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    QSize sizeHint() const;
};
```

Here is source file:

```
void HorizontalTabWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < count(); index++)
    {
        QPainter * painter = new QPainter(this);
        painter->begin(this);
        painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
        painter->setFont(QFont("Arial", 10));
        QRect tabrect = tabRect(index);
        painter->drawText(tabrect, Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::TextDontClip, tabText(index));
        painter->end();
    }
}

QSize HorizontalTabWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(130, 130);
}
```

I use it by creating NewTabWidget class that inherits QTabWidget. In the constructor of NewTabWidget I use:

```
setTabBar(new HorizontalTabWidget);
```

This is done just to be able to use that tabWidget because setTabBar is protected. Here is what I get:
[image]

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
What I want to create is this but with icons on the top and the labels under the icons (as in Qt Creator):
[image]

Comment: What do you want it to look like? What are you expecting from Qt::AlignVCenter?

Comment: Is it about that "CustomerList" text? If you want to center this, you should use AlignHCenter. And I wouldn't call this class "HoriontalTabWidget" if the actual order of tabs is vertical. (I think this kind is often referred to as AcoordionTab)

Comment: You could draw the text on the QRect defined by the icon as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270229/qt-how-to-set-text-on-top-of-qlabel-image. If your last edit is an actual result of your current code, then you could add painter->rotate(90) as a last step.

Comment: The last edit is the screenshot where I use QTabWidget without changing paintEvent().

Comment: From that question you referred to: "Solved! Just changed the method sizeHint in tabSizeHint and it works well :)"

Here is the source code for the tab widget used in Qt Creator:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/fancytabwidget.cpp

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/fancytabwidget.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem should be in the paint method; check if an example below would work for you, it should draw tabs the same way QTCreator does. I've reused the original tab style [QStyleOptionTabV3](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstyleoptiontabv3.html) to do majority of paint work and then just rendered icon and tab's text on top of the image it produced:

```
class TestTabBar : public QTabBar
{
public:
    explicit TestTabBar(QWidget* parent=0) : QTabBar(parent)
    {
        setIconSize(QSize(80, 80));
    }

protected:
    QSize tabSizeHint(int) const
    {
        return QSize(80, 80);
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStylePainter p(this);
        for (int index = 0; index < count(); index++)
        {
            QStyleOptionTabV3 tab;
            initStyleOption(&tab, index);

            QIcon tempIcon = tab.icon;
            QString tempText = tab.text;
            tab.icon = QIcon();
            tab.text = QString();

            p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTab, tab);

            QPainter painter;
            painter.begin(this);
            QRect tabrect = tabRect(index);
            tabrect.adjust(0, 8, 0, -8);
            painter.drawText(tabrect, Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignHCenter, tempText);
            tempIcon.paint(&painter, 0, tabrect.top(), tab.iconSize.width(), tab.iconSize.height(), Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignHCenter);    
            painter.end();
        }
    }
};

class TestTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
public:
    explicit TestTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QTabWidget(parent)
    {
        setTabBar(new TestTabBar());
    }
};
```

tabwidget init:

```
TestTabWidget* test = new TestTabWidget(this);
test->setGeometry(20, 20, 300, 200);
test->addTab(new QWidget(), QIcon("icon0.png"), "test0");
test->addTab(new QWidget(), QIcon("icon1.png"), "test1");
test->setTabPosition(QTabWidget::West);
```

this worked fine on my ubuntu, hope it gonna work for you, 
regards

Comment: To paint the icon for all tabs and to centre align the icon I used the following mod: 
tempIcon.paint(&painter, tabrect.left() + 4, tabrect.top() + (tabrect.height() / 2) - (tab.iconSize.height() / 2), tab.iconSize.width(), tab.iconSize.height());

Answer (score 1):

Vasiliy, thanks for fixing the double QPainter bug.

However, calling setTabIcon() and setTabText() from within paintEvent() leads to an infinite recursion. Remember that tab is a local object, so

```
tab.text = QString();
```

does not affect tabText().

So, the example can also be written without making temporary copies and do

```
p.drawText(tabrect, Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignHCenter, tabText(index));
tabIcon(index).paint(&p, tabrect, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example does not work. leads to a fall program.

bring your own example with minor edits
- my system qt 4.6.3 for Windows and VS2008

```
class TestTabBar : public QTabBar
{
public:
    explicit TestTabBar(QWidget* parent=0) : QTabBar(parent)
    {
        setIconSize(QSize(58, 68));
    }

protected:
    QSize tabSizeHint(int) const
    {
        return QSize(58, 68);
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
    {
        QStylePainter p(this);

        for (int index = 0; index < count(); index++)
        {
            QStyleOptionTabV3 tab;
            initStyleOption(&tab, index);

            QIcon tempIcon = tabIcon(index);
            QString tempText = this->tabText(index);

            QRect tabrect = tabRect(index);

            tab.icon = QIcon();
            tab.text = QString();

            p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTab, tab);
            tabrect.adjust(0, 3, 0, -3);

            p.setPen(Qt::black);    
            p.setFont(QFont("Arial", 7));

            p.drawText(tabrect, Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignHCenter, tempText );
            tempIcon.paint(&p, tabrect, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignHCenter);

            this->setTabIcon(index, tempIcon );
            this->setTabText( index, tempText);
        }
    }
};

class TestTabWidget : public QTabWidget
{
public:
    explicit TestTabWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QTabWidget(parent)
    {
        setTabBar(new TestTabBar());
    }
};
```